# Iron Router Meteor , Router.go alternative from server-side

Tags: meteor, stripe-payments, iron-router

I am using Meteor with Iron Router and Stripe. Everything is working great, but I cant figure out how to re-direct user to a final order complete page after the Stripe charge is completed.

On my client side I have a modal box that appears which contains a button that says, "Pay" When the Pay button is clicked an event is fired that calls up and opens Stripe Checkout.

The Stripe Checkout then initiates on the client and the user is able to enter the card details and submit the payment. The server side method for charging the card thru Stripe is completed and I also have some other basic database tasks that are being performed to log the result and complete the order status.

I have created a route using Iron router that I want the user to be re-directed too after the Stripe Payment is completed.

As of now the modal box continues to stay on the screen. I am trying to make the Router.go send user to the order page that had been setup after the order is finished.

I beleive the Iron Router Router.go is used client-side only. How can I complete the order process and make the client-side modal box disappear after the Stripe charge is completed and re-direct user to a final complete page.

When I use the Router.go on server-side I am getting error:

```
Exception in callback of async function: TypeError: Object function router(req, res, next) {//XXX this assumes no other routers on the parent stack which we should probably fix
```

Comment: Can't you do router.go() in the callback of the meteor.call method after success?

Comment: I ended up doing basically what you said , and added this router.go after the meteor.call

Answer (score 0):

You can't force the user's browser away from it's page if you don't already have some logic on the page to "remote control it". Fortunately there are a number of options for the latter:

If you are using a router you could make the route itself reactive, depending on the content of a subscribed collection. Alternatively, you can have an `Tracker.autorun` or an `observeChanges` block on your client side code that checks for changes to that "control" collection and then execute `Router.go` accordingly.

As for the control collection, a simple collection like:

```
var Control = new Mongo.Collection('control');
```

would do, and then you insert into it from the server when the event occurs (`Control.insert({route: "newroute"})`), and check for content changes on the client, for instance like so:

```
Control.find().observeChanges({
  added: function(id, doc) {
    Router.go(doc.route);
  });
```